# I want to migrate the list of users windows 2008 r2 to windows 2016

Tags: migration, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2016

I want to migrate the list of my users from windows 2008 R2 to windows 2016.

I used "Windows Server Migration Tools" with the command
"Export-SmigServerSetting -User All -Group -Path C: \ -Verbose"

but the problem on the 2016 server when I place the order
"Import-SmigServerSetting -User All -Group -Path C: \ -Verbose"

it gives me an error
"Error: Import-SmigServerSetting: The migration operation cannot be performed. The versions of Windows Server Migration Tools on the source and destination servers are not the same. Please make sure that the same version of Windows Server Migration Tools is used on the source and destination server. "

can someone tell me where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I face the same issue in my case was from 2008 to 2012 and I could fix it following:

For context try to use the newer version, it means use the migration tool 2016,

- Create deployment folder on W2016 destination server
- Copy deployment folder over to W 2008 source server
- Register W 2016 Microsoft server migration tool on windows 2008
  source server